# Cannot find plugin for GDAL raster miscellaneous tools ( merge ) in newly installed QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal

I am using QGIS 3.8.3.

I'm looking for the Gdal tools "miscellaneous" under the raster menu. It does not appear, nor can I find where to install it in the plugins.

Specifically I am looking for the merge tool within miscellaneous.

Screenshot below. Any help?

[image]

Comment: Thats strange, I am not having that issue. Have you tried searching for it form the search bar at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: By the look of menu bar in your screenshot, which lacks `Processing` between `Mesh` and `Help`, your **Processing** in the Plugins Manager is likely unticked. Many ex-GDAL Tools belong to Processing Toolbox now.

Comment: @Kazuhito It may be worth adding some steps and making your comment an answer

Comment: Thanks @Midavalo Will do.

Answer (score 8):

I am just guessing, but you may find your **Processing** tool in the **Plugins Manager** window  (from `Menu > Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins`) without a tick (like below):

[image]

Then the menu will not show `Processing` menu in between `Mesh` and `Help`, and at the same time you miss lots of GDAL tools under the `Raster` menu.

[image]

Then please click on the tick box of the `Processing`.

[image]

You will be able to recover Raster processing tools.

[image]

Comment: this worked, thank you!

Comment: @perezoso_estudioso If this has answered your question please consider marking as the answer by clicking the Check mark.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thank you @Midavalo